# Stringizing operator in C not working on linux

Tags: c, operators, c-preprocessor

I have the following code which works as expected in Windows but on Ubuntu I get the error "toString1 was not declared in this scope".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define a                    2
#define b                    3
#define c                    4
#define d                    5
#define toString1(S)         #S
#define toString(S)          toString1(S)
#define numbers              a,b,c,d
#define numbersS             toString(numbers)
int main()
{
 int a1 = 0, a2 = 0, a3 = 0, a4 = 0;
 if (sscanf_s(numbersS, "%d,%d,%d,%d", &a1, &a2, &a3, &a4) == 4)
 { 
    printf("The numbers were assigned correctly");
 }
 printf("%d %d %d %d ", a1, a2, a3, a4);
}
```

What could be the reason for that?  If I remove toString1 and make

```
#define toString(S)           #S
```

the result is 0 for every variable on both Windows and Ubuntu.

Can someone have an explanation for this?

Comment: As it shows up on Windows, too, why did you make that Linux-specific? (It is not)

Comment: Which compiler -- even on Windows -- compiles a translation unit "as expected" that has a function call at global space and no `int main()`?

Comment: Always check the result of functions which might encounter an error. Post a [mcve]

Comment: The Microsoft C compiler is a bit "special". It's never been C99-compliant, for instance.

Comment: Sorry for the bad code sample, I was in hurry.

Comment: Generic curiosity aside, you *are* hopefully aware that this kind of preprocessor magic is very much frowned upon, and should be reserved for special cases that cannot conceivably be solved in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler says:

```
 error: macro "toString1" passed 4 arguments, but takes just 1

 sscanf(numbersS, "%d,%d,%d,%d",a1,a2,a3,a4);
```

indeed, `numbersS` is `toString(numbers)` and numbers `is a,b,c,d`

so you will need some variable macro magic here to work correctly:

```
#define a                    2
#define b                    3
#define c                    4
#define d                    5
#define toString1(S...)         #S
#define toString(S...)          toString1(S, __VA_ARGS__) 
#define numbers              a,b,c,d
#define numbersS             toString(numbers)

int main()
{
    int a1,a2,a3,a4;
    sscanf(numbersS, "%d,%d,%d,%d",&a1,&a2,&a3,&a4); 
    printf("%d %d %d %d", a1,a2,a3,a4);

}
```

Online: https://ideone.com/puPd6x

(Also, please note that I have fixed the sscanf to take addresses)

Comment: This compiles in gcc but not on Visual Studio. I can use the define for Unix only but there is nothing that can work on both?

Comment: @MStriker you always can use a `#ifdef _MSC_VER` to check for VS, and use a different set of macros for the tw compilers.

Comment: The variadic macro syntax used in this example is an (old) gcc extension and does not conform with standard C. Also, the use of __VA_ARGS__ is incorrect, since the gcc extension doesn't use __VA_ARGS__ and it will not be replaced. Use `#define toString1(...) #__VA_ARGS__` and `#define toString(S) toString1(S)`